Two plots won't show together
I'm trying to plot two revolution plots together.  Normally this works just fine, but for some reason I can't get this one to work.  I have no idea what's going on.  If I just put Show[P1] or Show[P2], each graph works fine. But when I try to do both, only the first one listed shows up. Any help would be greatly appreciated!
P1 = RevolutionPlot3D[{2*Cos[t], 2*Sin[t]}, {t, Pi/4, Pi/2}, 
   MeshStyle -> None, PlotStyle -> Blue, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}];
P2 = RevolutionPlot3D[s, {s, 0, 1}, MeshStyle -> None, 
   PlotStyle -> Red];
Show[P1, P2]


One way around this is to do the following
Show[P1, P2, PlotRange -> All]


Notice the option PlotRange -> All.
Show takes its options from the first Plot. But you can override this directly using options in the Show command itself.
